# Count for each ID how many variables

Tags: r, count

I would like to count how many time points have each ID for example:

```
  ID Time
1 A 0
2 A 1
3 B 0
4 C 0
5 C 1
6 C 2
7 D 0
```

so I have
Time 0 only: 2IDS that are: B and D
Time 0 and 1 only: 1ID that is: A
Time 1 only: none
Time 0 and 2: none
Time 0,1,2: 1ID that is: C

Thank you

Comment: this question is a little cryptic t understand. Please update with a clear language and description

Answer (score 0):

In base R, with two `aggregate`s:

```r
aggregate(Time ~ ID, data = df, FUN = \(x) toString(unique(x))) |>
  aggregate(ID ~ Time, data = _, FUN = unique)

     Time   ID
1       0 B, D
2    0, 1    A
3 0, 1, 2    C
```

Or with `tapply`:

```r
tapply(df$Time, df$ID, toString) %>% 
  tapply(names(.), ., toString)

#      0    0, 1 0, 1, 2 
# "B, D"     "A"     "C"
```

---

Or in `dplyr`:

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(Time = toString(Time)) %>% 
  group_by(Time) %>% 
  summarise(ID = toString(ID))

# A tibble: 3 × 2
  Time    ID   
  <chr>   <chr>
1 0       B, D 
2 0, 1    A    
3 0, 1, 2 C
```

Comment: Thanks Mael! And if I want to count how many IDs I have in my 0;  0&1 etc using dplyr method how can I do this?

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63062416/count-unique-combinations-of-variable-values-in-an-r-dataframe-column